# In Javascript, why I can't draw multiple instance of my object?

Tags: javascript, html, class, canvas, multiple-instances

I'm trying to create a basic game engine using the canvas tag in HTML5 and javascript.

But I'm having trouble to create two distinct instance of the Balle class in the following code and I cannot see why.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script>
// Description des Classes

// Classe Point2D
function Point2D (x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Classe Box2D
function Box2D (x, y, width, height)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

//Classe CanvasObject
function CanvasObject(context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
    this.lineWidth = 1;
    this.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.boundingBox2D = new Box2D (0, 0, 0, 0);
}

// Détection de collision par boîte 2D.
CanvasObject.prototype.collides = function (b) {
    var left = (this.boundingBox2D.x < b.boundingBox2D.x + b.boundingBox2D.width);
    var right = (this.boundingBox2D.x + this.boundingBox2D.width > b.boundingBox2D.x);
    var top = (this.boundingBox2D.y + this.boundingBox2D.height > b.boundingBox2D.y);
    var bottom = (this.boundingBox2D.y < b.boundingBox2D.y + b.boundingBox2D.height);

    return left && right && top && bottom;
};

// Classe Arc
// Paramètres :
//    context <-- Contexte d'animation
function Arc(context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.center = new Point2D(0, 0);
    this.start = 0;
    this.end = 0;
    this.radius = 0;
    this.counterClockwise = false;
}

// Héritage de CanvasObject
Arc.prototype = new CanvasObject(this.context);

// Fonction mettant à jour la bounding box autour de la balle
// Nécessaire car c'est un cercle...
Arc.prototype.update = function () {
    this.boundingBox2D.x = this.center.x - this.radius;
    this.boundingBox2D.y = this.center.y - this.radius;
    this.boundingBox2D.width = 2 * this.radius;
    this.boundingBox2D.height = 2 * this.radius;
};

// Méthode pour dessiner
Arc.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc (this.center.x, this.center.y, this.radius, this.start, this.end, this.counterClockWise);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    this.context.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
    this.context.stroke();    
};

// Classe Balle
function Balle (context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.start = 0;
    this.end = 2 * Math.PI;
}

Balle.prototype = new Arc(this.context);


// FIN DÉCLARATION DE CLASSE

// Fonction permettant d'établir le FPS du browser
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

// Declare global variables
var lastTime;

// Objets
var balle;
var testArc;

var canvas;
var context;

var pressedKeys;
var d;
var log;

function initialize()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    pressedKeys = [];
    d = document.getElementById("divTest");
    log = document.getElementById("log");

    var date = new Date();
    lastTime = date.getTime();

    // Initialize the global variables
    balle = new Balle (context);
    balle.center.x = canvas.width / 2;
    balle.center.y = canvas.height / 2;
    balle.radius = 10;
    balle.speed = 75;
    balle.pixelPerFrame = 0;
    balle.dX = 1;
    balle.dY = 1;
    balle.nitro = 1;
    balle.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    balle.lineWidth = 1;

    testArc = new Balle (context);

    testArc.center.x = canvas.width *.75;
    testArc.center.y = canvas.height * .75;
    testArc.radius = 25;
    testArc.lineWidth = 3;
}


// Update position of objects
function update()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;

    var ppfFactor = timeDiff / 1000;

    updateBalle(ppfFactor);

    lastTime = time;
}

// Mise à jour de la balle
// Paramètres :
// ppfFactor : pixelPerFrame factor
function updateBalle(ppfFactor)
{


    balle.pixelPerFrame = balle.speed * ppfFactor;

    if (pressedKeys[17])
        balle.nitro = 5;
    else
        balle.nitro = 1;

    if (pressedKeys[37] || pressedKeys[39])
        if (pressedKeys[39])
            balle.dX = 1;
        else
            balle.dX = -1;
    else
        balle.dX = 0;

//    if (!balle.collides (testArc))
        balle.center.x = balle.center.x + (balle.pixelPerFrame * balle.dX * balle.nitro);

    if (pressedKeys[38] || pressedKeys[40])
        if (pressedKeys[40])
            balle.dY = 1;
        else
            balle.dY = -1;
    else
        balle.dY = 0;

//    if (!balle.collides (testArc))
        balle.center.y = balle.center.y + (balle.pixelPerFrame * balle.dY * balle.nitro);

    balle.update();
    testArc.update();    

}

// draw objects
function draw()
{
    // clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    testArc.draw();
    balle.draw();
}

// Boucle continue d'animation
function animate(){

    // update
    update();

    // draw
    draw();

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
}


window.onload = function(){
    // initialize stage
    initialize();

    animate();
};


window.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    var e = window.event || e;

    if (d)
        d.innerHTML = "Key Code : " + e.keyCode + " Collision : " + balle.collides(testArc);

    pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

window.onkeyup = function (e)
{
    var e = window.event || e;

    pressedKeys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="c" width="640" height="480">
</canvas>
<div id="divTest"></div>
<ul id="log">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: what _kind_ of **trouble** exactly ?

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Where you you creating two instances of your object? You should try and pare your code down to as basic an example as possible.

Comment: this kind of statement is not correct `Arc.prototype = new CanvasObject(this.context);`. At the moment of execution, `this` refers to the global scope, and thus have no `context` property.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the way you have done your inheritance, specifically this line:

```
Balle.prototype = new Arc(this.context);
```

This means that all instances of the Balle class will share the same instance of the Arc class as their prototype, so when you update the center of one balle, they all update.

You should look into a better method of handling inheritance, a popular one is John Resig's method http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/.